# Class not found in psr-4 composer autoloading

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

I have a base folder with a vendor folder which include composer folder and my created folder src. The src folder contain all classes required to work.

In src folder, I have class example below

```
<?php

    namespace Test;

    class Example{
        public function display(){
            echo "This is Example Class";
        }
    }

 ?>
```

my composer.json has following content:

```
{
    "autoload":{
        "psr-4":{
            "Test\\":"src"
        }
    }   
}
```

and finally I am creating the instance of example class in a test file in base folder:

```
<?php

    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    $a=new Test\Example();
    $a->display();


?>
```

The issue is when i try to run test file the following error occurred: **[Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Test\Example' not found.]**

Please help me what I am doing wrong, [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARXPh.png) is the screen shot of  directory structure.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have `src` inside of `vendor` directory?

Comment: Yes insider vendor directory

Comment: `vendor` directory is only for dependencies and should be fully managed by Composer - at any point you should be able to remove it and restore it by calling `composer install`. Don't put your own files inside of it.

Comment: Yes thanks, i put the src folder in base directory and it worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest I'm not sure where your `src`, `testing.php` and `composer.json` are located, but they should be located in main directory (in your case 2-Basic-example and not in `vendor` directory).  Then just run:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

and it should work assuming your `Example` class is saved as `Example.php` in `src` directory

Comment: Thanks marcin, moving src folder in base directory works for me.